# Accessing file via URL

Tags: python-3.x, web-services, flask, heroku, apple-app-site-association

I deployed a python flask app on Heroku and it works fine. I have also uploaded a well-known folder that contains an apple-app-site association file, but when I try to access the file via [URL](https://intelitydeeplink.herokuapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-association), it returns 404. Basically, I'm testing universal links, so I wanted the apple-app-site association to be accessible. When I checked the status in the branch.io aasa validator, it returns server error, please find attached the screenshot [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/memUz.png)

What I'm doing wrong?

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/well-known')
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h1>Welcome to Universal Link - iOS<h1>"
```

wsgi.py

```
from app.main import app
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

Comment: Have you set up a route in flask to cover serving this file?

Comment: @JonSG you mean in the main.py file? I have linked the folder, I have updated the question with main.py file